# Use the resulting variable of a button as variable for another one

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

Sorry if the title is a bit confusing, I did not know how to word it better.

I'm having the following problem: I'm using the filedialog function of Tkinter to select multiple csv files once a button is pressed and then I'm treating those files to get several values as pandas dataframes. After that, I want to use those pandas dataframes in a function that will be used for another button, but I'm unable to take those dataframes outside their initial function. One of the main problems that I have trying to do this is that, due to the for loop used, the dataframe is overriten everytime the loop hapens, so I usually end up with only the last rt. The ideal thing would be to be able to put the function that the second button(convItol) would call inside the select function(the one used to upload the files) but I don't know if it could be done that way.

Here's my code so far:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import glob, os
from pandas import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
import ntpath
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

#create window
window=Tk()

#textlist
screen=Listbox(window, height=10, width=50)
screen.grid(column=0, row=1, rowspan=4, columnspan=8)

#scrollbar
scrollbar=Scrollbar(window)
scrollbar.grid(row=2, column=8, sticky=S+N)
screen.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.configure(command=screen.yview)

#separator for the buttons
separator=Frame(height=2,bd=1, relief=SUNKEN)
separator.grid(row=2,column=20)


#selectfiles
def select():
    selector=filedialog.askopenfilenames(parent=window,
    initialdir="/", title="Upload")
    for file in selector:
        filename=ntpath.basename(file)
        rt=pandas.read_csv(file, skiprows=6)
        rt.set_index('Peak')
        #rt is the pandas dataframe that I want to use in another function

#select button:
browse=Button(separator, text="Browse", command=select, width=10)
browse.grid(row=0, column=1)

#Conversion ITol function
def ConversionItol():
    #here is where I would like to use the rt pandas dataframe

#Itol conversion Button
convItol=Button(separator, text="Conversion ITol", command=ConversionItol)
convItol.grid(row=1,column=1)
convSty=Button(separator, text="Conversion Sty")
convSty.grid(row=2, column=1)

window.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable, which you create at the top of your file.

```
data = 'whatever'
```

Then you just add these two lines to `select()`:

```
global data
data = rt
```

Then add the line `global data` to `ConversionItol()` and you can use `rt` as `data`. Hope that helped.